# How can i do Inset FAB using Material UI in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, next.js

i'm currently i'm working in a project that is required to have a "Inset Fab" button between containers. I saw in the Material Design documentation that the name of the component is called "Inset FAB", i'd got some tutorials on google (but didn't find many) on how to implement, but normally they are "workaround" (setting a background border with radius behind the button). I'm still puzzled in how to do it.
Currently i'm using the MUI/Material UI 5.

[Example of inset Fab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzA3E.png)

Comment: Please add some of you code and tell us some of the things you've tried. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get more info on how to ask good questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what I understand inset is done through box shadows.
specifically

```
boxShadow: "0px 0px 0px 5px white inset"
```

here is a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mui-forked-8omkz?file=/index.js) I threw together

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Box, Fab } from "@material-ui/core";

const appBarStyle = {
  height: "100px",
  backgroundColor: "blue",
  position: "relative"
};
const fabWithInset = {
  position: "absolute",
  backgroundColor: "red",
  boxShadow: "0px 0px 0px 0px white inset",
  left: "50%",
  bottom: "0px",
  transform: "translate(0%,50%)",
  "&:onclick": {
    boxShadow: "0px 0px 0px 5px white inset"
  }
};
function App() {
  return (
    <Box style={appBarStyle}>
      <Fab style={fabWithInset} />
    </Box>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```